# excel date is coming as a integer value in java

Tags: java, xssf

```
public void new1() throws IOException, ParseException ,DateTimeParseException { 
String excelpath="C:\\Users\\Rudra\\Desktop\\saba.xlsx";
 File file=new File(excelpath);
 FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file);
 workbook =new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
 worksheet=workbook.getSheetAt(0);   
 for(int  i=1;i<worksheet.getLastRowNum();i++) {
     //first name
     cell=worksheet.getRow(i).getCell(3);       
          cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
                System.out.print("  "+" "+cell.getStringCellValue());
     }
}
```

**outputis:41789Unparseable date: "40788"(excel sheet date is coimg as integer in java  )**

Answer (score 0):

Give the variable of the date so that your question is more explicit. You can always use

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

.........More code..........

int value=41789;
datestring=value.toString();
SimpleDateFormat ft=new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
String mydate= ft.parse(datestring);
```